# Way to fetch list of orders based on customer email StripeJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm building a small ecommerce site with nextjs to get to know Stripe and I'm wondering if there's a way to, based on the users email or customer_id, to fetch a list of all orders that would include the products they've bought. I've been checking their docs but the only thing I can find is for subscriptions which I'm not using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using PaymentIntents, you can list all payments made by a specific customer by passing a customer ID. In Node.js, it would look something like this:

```js
const paymentIntents = await stripe.paymentIntents.list({
  customer: "cu_xxx"
});
```

And you could do something similar [with charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=node) if needed.